# Tool to execute commands to draw lines and rectangles

Tags: python, graphics

I submitted a project and never heard back and I am wondering if my coding style is okay. At the company I work I get feedback, but I'd like to hear from the outside world. 
It's a drawing tool - the input is in a text file (each on its own line):

> C 20 4
>
> L 1 2 6 2
>
> L 6 3 6 4
>
> R 16 1 20 3

It's called as so: python drawingtool.py < input.txt

C = Canvas create, L = Line, R = Rectangle

```
from collections import defaultdict
import logging
import sys

NEWLINE = '\n'
DATA_SEP = '/'
PARAM_SEP = ' '
DATA_POS = 1
PARAM_POS = 0

class Canvas(object):
    _created = 0
    def __init__(self, cols, rows):
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols
        Canvas._created += 1
        self.surface = self._create_blank_canvas()

    def _create_blank_canvas(self):
        row_frame_char = '-'
        col_frame_char = '|'
        canvas = []
        top_bottom = [row_frame_char for col in xrange(self.cols+2)]
        middle = [self._middle_char(col, col_frame_char, self.cols+1) for col in xrange(self.cols+2)]
        for row in xrange(self.rows+2):
            if row == 0 or row == self.rows+2:
                canvas.append(list(top_bottom))
            else:
                canvas.append(list(middle))
        return canvas

    def _middle_char(self, col, col_frame_char, max):
        return col_frame_char if col == 0 or col == max else ' '

    def print_canvas(self):
        for row in self.surface:
            print ' '.join(row)

    def valid_pos(self, x, y):
        ret_val = False
        if not self._boundary(x, y) and self._on_canvas(x, y):
            ret_val = True
        return ret_val

    def _boundary(self, x, y):
        return (x == 0 or x == self.rows+1) or (y == 0 or y == self.cols+1)

    def _on_canvas(self, x, y):
        return (x > 0 and x < self.cols+1) or (y > 0 or y < self.rows+1)

    def update_cell(self, y, x, val=None):
        if self.valid_pos(y, x):
            self.surface[int(y)][int(x)] = val #[int(1)]
        else:
            logging.warning('Invalid position found x=%s y=%s' % (x,y))

class DataUtils(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw_data = None

    def prepare_data(self):
        return self.apply_strip(self.raw_data, '\n')

    def split_up_by_delimiter(self, data, delim):
        return [filter(lambda x:x, map(lambda x:x, y.split(delim))) for y in data]

    def read_data_lines(self):
        return sys.stdin.readlines()

    def write_data_lines(self, data):
        self._sys_write(data)

    def _sys_write(self, data):
        return sys.stdout.write(data)

    def _strip(self, text, char):
        return text.strip(char)

    def apply_strip(self, array_data, char):
        return map(lambda x:self._strip(x, char), array_data)

class Drawing_data(DataUtils):
    def __init__(self):
        self.raw_data = self.read_data_lines()

def process_q(command_q):
    MAX_ATTEMPTS = 5
    attempts = 0
    canvas = None
    while command_q and attempts < MAX_ATTEMPTS:

        inspect_command = command_q[0]
        command = inspect_command[1].split(' ')[0]
        if not Canvas._created and command <> 'C':
            attempts += 1
            logging.error('Cant draw no canvas created skipping') #args[0].split(' ')
        else:
            request = command_q.pop(0)
            function, data = request[0], request[1].split(' ')

            if command == 'C' and Canvas._created == 0:
                canvas = request[0](data)
            else:
                request[0](data, canvas)

        if Canvas._created > 0:
            canvas.print_canvas()

# all calls expect the whole command line
def C(args):
    canvas = Canvas(int(args[1]), int(args[2]))
    return canvas

def L(args, canvas):
    _, startx, starty, finishx, finishy = args
    direction_x = False
    var, fixed, stop, increment = 0, 0, 0, 1
    #if canvas.valid_pos(startx, starty) and canvas.valid_pos(finishx, finishy):
    if (int(startx) - int(finishx)): #x is not fixed, y is fixed
        increment, var = (-1, int(startx)) if int(finishx) - int(startx) < 0 else (1, int(startx))
        fixed = starty
        stop = abs(int(finishx) - var) + int(startx)
    else: #x is fixed, y is not fixed
        increment, var = (-1, int(starty)) if int(finishy) - int(starty) < 0 else (1, int(starty))
        fixed = startx
        stop = abs(int(finishy) - var) + int(starty)
        direction_x = True

    while var <= stop:
        if direction_x:
            canvas.update_cell(var, fixed, 'x')
        else:
            canvas.update_cell(fixed, var, 'x')
        var += increment
    #else:


def R(args, canvas):
    _, startx, starty, finishx, finishy = args
    L(['L', startx, starty, startx, finishy], canvas)
    L(['L', startx, starty, finishx, starty], canvas)
    L(['L', startx, finishy, finishx, finishy], canvas)
    L(['L', finishx, starty, finishx, finishy], canvas)

def B(args, canvas):
    pass

def unhandled(args, canvas):
    logging.error('unhandled command:%s for canvas %s' % (args, canvas))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    drawing_data = Drawing_data()
    drawing_data = drawing_data.prepare_data()
    dispatcher = {'C':C, 'L':L, 'R':R, 'B':B}
    command_q = []
    for data in drawing_data:
        command = dispatcher.get(data[0], unhandled)
        command_q.append([command,data])

    process_q(command_q)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, there should be two blank lines between top-level functions/classes/code blocks. You've also styled the class `Drawing_data`. It should be appropriately renamed to `DrawingData`.

Secondly, the class `Drawing_data` is completely pointless. Is there any reason why `self.data = self.read_data_lines()` can't be part of the `DataUtils` class?

While I understand your logic behind naming your actual drawing functions `C`, `L`, `R`, and `B`, it'd be better if you gave them better names, like `canvas`, and `line`

You also shouldn't be using `%` for string formatting. If you're running Python 2.6 or higher, string formatting with `%` is deprecated, and [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.Formatter.format) should be used instead. Here's an example of how to use `str.format`:

```
# str.format without positional or named arguments
print "{} {}".format("Hello", "world")

# str.format with positional arguments
print "{1} {0}".format("world", "Hello")

# str.format with named arguments
print "{word1} {word2}".format(word1="Hello", word2="world")
```

I'm also noticing a pattern with your inputted commands. The always form a structure somewhat like this: `[name] [integer] ...`. While it works with a small example like this, if you have bigger commands, I'd recommend giving them actual command names, and doing something like this: `canvas width:20 height:20`. It makes things a lot clearer to read.

Finally, I'd recommend adding [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to your code. Right now, nothing in your code file has docstrings. Here's an example of docstrings in use:

```
"""
This docstring is at the top of the file,
it should describe the purpose of this file.
"""


class MyClass(object):
    """
    Describe your class and it's arguments here.
    """
    ...

def my_func( ... ):
    """
    Describe your function and it's arguments here.
    """
    ...
```

Comment: @Michael No problem! Always willing to help out! :)

Comment: With your feedback, I've refactored much of the logic to standardize the row, col references and simplified the logic around making the lines.